# Using synchronized block to protect against infinite loops

Tags: java, parallel-processing, synchronized, locks

I'm currently developing an app that in some test cases, goes on a infinite loop, but if I redo the same tests, it goes on well. To prevent it, I'm using a secondary thread to monitor the time passed since the start of a task, but I'm currently not using synchronized blocks, because I don't know how to.

Here is an example:

```
public class ThreadHarvest {
    private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static boolean safe;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread task = new Thread(() ->{
            lock.lock();
            safe = false;

            for (long i = 10000000L; i > 0L; --i)
                System.out.println(i);

            safe = true;
            lock.unlock();

            System.out.println("Safe ended!");
        });

        task.start();

        while (lock.isLocked() == false);

        lock.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (!safe)
        {
            task.stop();
            System.out.println("Force ended!");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, there is a specific area that is guaranteed to be safe, which is just after the lock is released. And I know too that the stop method is deprecated, so if you happen to have some good ideas to make it less error prone, I'd be very thankful :D

Comment: Note: As `boolean safe` is not volatile, your main thread might not see that change.

Comment: Synchronization isn't a defence against infinite loops, but it is a possible way to convert them into deadlocks. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PeterLawrey iirc, `ReentrantLock` also make sure the change being visible. (you may Google for `java reentrantlock memory barrier`).  The way OP using it *seems* working fine (need more inspection though :P )

Comment: OP: afaik, there is no proper way in Java to "force" ending a thread.  You may want to search for how to deal with similar situation by Googling `Java thread interrupt`.  In brief, your thread should be rewritten to prepare for interruption, and your main thread interrupt corresponding thread to try to stop them from continue working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but here are some general comments about your code.

- You should never have a spin loop like that.  I'd add a `Thread.sleep(10);` or something.
- With locks, you should always put your unlock in a `lock; try {  } finally { unlock; }`.  Then you know your lock will be unlocked even if it throws an exception.
- If you are accessing a field in two different threads you must protect it somehow.  You could use an `AtomicBoolean` for `safe` or mark it as a `volatile boolean` otherwise the main thread might not see any changes to it.  There are no guarantees of memory synchronization with `isLocked()` or `tryLock()`.
- Instead of your lock and safe, how about just trying to do a `task.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` and then test `if (task.isAlive()) { killItWithFire(); }`.

> I'm currently developing an app that in some test cases, goes on a infinite loop,

Seems to me like you should be be concentrating your time fixing this problem.  The `thread.stop()` is a real hack.

Comment: one opinion: it should be `lock; try {...} finally {unlock;}` instead.  You don't want to unlock if there is anything wrong happen in lock

Comment: Another thing is, I doubt if using `AtomicBoolean` or `volatile` is needed here.  `ReentrantLock` is also serving the purpose for memory barrier (just like `synchronized`)

Comment: Good point wrt the lock @AdrianShum.   Fixed.  Safe can be set to true _before_ the !safe test which may be ok but I'd rather be safe, especially since the `tryLock(...)` makes no guarantee about memory synchronization according to the docs unless it's successful.

Comment: @Gary oh you are right. I originally thought the last part of `!safe` checking happens after successful tryLock